# Filter in CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I wrote a Method like below

```
-(NSArray*)getClubDetailedDeals:(NSString *)clubID{

    NSError *error;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ClubDetailsDeals"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *fetchedArray1 = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

    ClubDetailsDealsDAO *obb = [fetchedArray1 objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"MY ID IS %@ and count is %d", obb.dealname, [fetchedArray1 count]);




    NSLog(@"deal is %@", clubID);

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K CONTAINS %@)", @"clubid", clubID];

    //NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dealid contains[cd] %@", dealID];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *fetchedArray = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"COUNT of arary is ~~~~ %d", [fetchedArray count]);

    return fetchedArray;
}
```

Here, the count of Array in this LOG is

***        NSLog(@"MY ID IS %@ and count is %d", obb.dealname, [fetchedArray1 count]);***

is showing more than one elements, as more I add, its increasing properly.

But when I fetch it using this query

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K CONTAINS %@)", @"clubid", clubID];
```

Its returning nothing, even the OBJECT is available in CoreData.

So what is right query to fetch by match clubid, i.e NSString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
-(NSArray*)getClubDetailedDeals:(NSString *)clubID{

    NSError *error;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ClubDetailsDeals"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dealid
 contains[cd] %@)", clubID]];

    NSArray *fetchedArray = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"COUNT of arary is ~~~~ %d", [fetchedArray count]);

    return fetchedArray;
}
```

Comment: [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dealid
 contains[cd] %@)", clubID]];

Comment: Thanks, It works, Let me know cause dear as you have time, I have accepted the answer :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217269/how-to-delete-the-coredata-objects-with-user-defined-id

Comment: Have a look on this, its also my query dear.