# How to delete the CoreData Objects with user-defined id?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have object like this

```
@interface Clubs : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * catname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubdescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * distance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * logopath;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubtype;

@end
```

I want to delete only those object have are particular clubid?

Suppose there are twenty clubs are added to CoreData, only these object I want to delete whose clubid is 120.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, you have to fetch all results for that id and loop over them, deleting them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    -(void)deleteClubsEntity:(NSString*)clubId // pass the value 120
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        NSFetchRequest * fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

       [fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Clubs" inManagedObjectContext: context]];
       [fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(clubid
 contains[cd] %@)",clubId]];

       NSArray * records = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
           for (NSManagedObject * record in records) {
                [context deleteObject:record];
            }
       [context save:&error];
    }
```

Comment: [records setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(@"(clubID contains[cd] %@)", clubId]];


Here is formatting issue dear, see @, "", are these okay?

Answer (score 1):

There's no batch Core Data method for deleting a set of objects matching a predicate. You will have to retrieve them and delete them by iterating through the results.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = // get the managed object context
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Clubs"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"clubid == 120"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *entitiesToDelete = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *entity in entitiesToDelete) {
    [moc deleteObject:entity];
}
[moc save:&error];
if (error) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: This did not exist back then, but iOS 8 introduced `NSBatchUpdateRequest`